# jQuery. Call one property-function from another

Tags: jquery

I have a `$form.validate` -class in which I would like to be able to call one property-method from another. Is this possible?

```
$form.validate({
  ,onfocusout: function(element) {
    // In this property-function I would like to go call invalidHandler like a method
  }, 
  invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
    // do stuff
  }
```

Comment: You cannot invoke `invalidHandler` directly, however you could extract the logic to a function and call that from both locations.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Rory McCrossan.
Solution is to break out the code one wishes to call into a method.